# Beginner python - simple Pounds to Kilos

Tags: python-3.x

The instructions are very simple, but I am struggling none the less. We have learned very few things in this class so far, so I am looking for a very simplistic answer.

The instructions are as follows "Write  a   Python  program  that   will    prompt   the    user     to enter   a   weight  in  pounds,  then
convert it  to  kilograms   and output  the result. Note,   one pound   is  .454    kilograms"

What i have so far is

`print("Pounds to Kilos. Please Enter value in pounds.")`

`x=input('Pounds: ')`

`float(x)`

`print(x * .454)`

Comment: `x = float(x)` for starters

Comment: Karl, if you found a suitable answer, please confirm one of them so others know the question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the variable **x**'s value to the `float`, but not assigning it to anything. So, the real value which **x** variable holds never changed. You **did not** edit the **x** variable in fact. You can try something like this;

```
print("Pounds to Kilos. Please Enter value in pounds.")

x=float(input('Pounds: '))

print(x * .454)
```

However, using functions in that nested manner is not recommended. Instead, initialize a new variable to hold the new **float-converted** value;

```
print("Pounds to Kilos. Please Enter value in pounds.")

x = input('Pounds: ')

x_float = float(x)

print(x_float * .454)
```

Comment: Why is it not recommended? Is it due to the explicit not implicit rule?

Comment: It is not recommended to make your code looks nested like this, it reduces the readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Going from your code example I would do something like this.

```
print("Pounds to Kilos. Please Enter value in pounds.")

x = float(input('Pounds: '))

print(x * 0.454, "kg")
```

**EDIT**

Maybe instead of having the calculation in the `print()` statement I add a separate variable for it, including the advise about `float` from the other solution.

```
print("Pounds to Kilos. Please Enter value in pounds.")

x = (input('Pounds: '))

kg = float(x) * 0.454

print(kg, "kg")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:** First you ask the user's weight using input command, then you can print a message saying converting to kgs.. (it's optional). create a new variable called weight_kgs to convert the user's input to a float, then multiply the input by 0.45. after that convert the weight_kgs variable to a string once again by making a new variable called final_weight, so that you can join the input by user to a string. At the end print a message telling the user's weight. print("you weight is " + final_weight)

````
```
weight_lbs = input("enter your weight(lbs): ")
print("converting to kgs...")
weight_kgs = float(weight_lbs) * 0.45
final_weight = str(weight_kgs)
print("your weight is " + final_weight + "kgs") # line 5
```
````

I hope you got it.

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works, how can one learn from it?